# How to get the number of columns in a list control

Tags: winapi, comdlg32

I need to get the number of columns in a list control in report mode.

Right now I'm sending a `LVM_GETCOLUMN` with increasing column number until `SendMessage` returns `FALSE`:

```
int col;
for (col = 0;; col++)
{ 
  LVCOLUMN Column;
  Column.mask = LVCF_WIDTH;
  if (!::SendMessage(hWnd, LVM_GETCOLUMN, col, (LPARAM)Column)
    break;
}
```

But this is rather awkward.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can retrieve the number of columns from the header control of the list control.

```
HWND hWndHdr = (HWND)::SendMessage(hWnd, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
int count = (int)::SendMessage(hWndHdr, HDM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0L);
```

Comment: On the other hand, columns have to added to the ListView using [`LVM_INSERTCOLUMN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761101.aspx), so you could just keep track of how many columns your code has added.  Unless you are querying a ListView that you do not have control over...